# EXCEL How do I ignore a cell if a cell has a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row that will have weekly values entered. Column B has the initial value, and E has the calculation; as I add values to C, D and so on, I want the calculation to skip the previous columns value when the next column gets a value.

B1-C1=E1 BUT when a value is added to D1, E1 would update to B1-D1=E1

Sorry for the horrible description. This is probably answered somewhere on this site but I am not sure what terms to search.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you actual data is as simple as your sample data you could just use:

```
=IF(LEN(D2)>0, B2-D2,B2-C2)
```

You could also use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2), B2-C2, B2-D2)
```

if you prefer but Len is a little shorter and I believe the `ISBLANK()` function has flaws, If you have a formula in `D2` that has a calculation and you set the result to `""` then it will pick up as false. It depends on your needs.

Comment: Great suggestions. 1 change. The logic in the `ISBLANK` option needs to be switched as `ISBLANK` will evaluate to `TRUE` rather than `FALSE`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering this so fast. My sample was definitely simple and I was hoping to extend out what I learned here but it does not seem to be that easy. So here is what I want to cover:

B2-C2 (if there is a value in D2 then (B2-D2 unless there is value in E2 then (B2-E2 unless there is a value in F2)))...this out to L2

Every week, for 10 weeks, I will get a new value to measure against B2 so I want to put that new weekly value into the next cell, C2 - L2, with the calculation going into M2. M2 will give me the new difference while retaining what the new weekly value is. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can use an if statement. I am not 100% sure of your problem but something like this might be helpful.

```
if(A1, A1, 0)
```

So for your example provided.

```
=B1-if(D1, D1, C1)
```

This says if there is a value in D1 use D1 else use C1. This works in this example, because if
D1 is empty or 0 you will use the other cell. This may change for any given problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if function in E1:

```
=IF(D1>0,B1-D1,IF(C1>0,B1-C1,B1))
```

Then enter a value in B1, then C1 then D1 to see the results.

According to your question, you only have room for two entries after the default B1 value.  This statement will handle that.

If you need more fields, nest more if functions.  But if's can only be nested 7 deep, so you can only have an initial value in B1 and 7 more cells, C1 to I1 with your formula in J1

Comment: This would fail if the value in D1 was 0, and should be subtracted, Also would fail if the value of `D2` was `""` it would be a false true. On top of those you could eliminate the second if, because `B1` minus nothing willl still be `B1`

Comment: You are correct, however I made the assumption that a numeric value would be added.  This is the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following.

In E1 paste the following:

=A1-INDEX(B1:D1,1,COUNT(B1:D1))

The count formula will tell how many values are present in the range of B:D column. This will be used to catch the last column with an index formula which will be deducted form A1.

One thing is very important! The values from A to D has to be written in sequence, if one column is missing than the calculation will be false.

Hope I could help!

Comment: This would be much much slower over along range then a simple if.Also would fail if C was blank and D had a value.

Comment: Depends how many columns you have. If there are 15 columns than you have to make a complex nested IF formula. With my formula the range can be easily adjusted.

Comment: With more Columns, it would be much more efficient to use `=A1-LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B1:D1)`and accurate also.also it wouldn't be affected by blanks in between the first and last cells of the row